# Independence on finite sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $\Omega$ be an *n-element* set with uniform probability and let $A, B \subset \Omega$ be independent. Show that if $A$ has $i$ elements, then $B$ must have,

$$j = k \frac{n}{gcd(i,n)}$$ elements, where $k \in  \{0,1,...,gcd(i,n) \}$.

($gcd(i,n)$ denotes the *greatest common divisor* of $i,n$)

**My attempt**:

By independence of $A,B$ we know, $P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$. I denote the number of elements in $P(A\cap B)$ as $m$, the elements in $P(B)$ as $j$ and the elements in $P(A)$ as $i$.

From,

$$ \frac{i}{n}\frac{j}{n} = \frac{m}{n}$$

so,

$$ij = mn$$
$$ j = \frac{mn}{i}$$

must hold.

From here I want to somehow show that the integers $k$ as requested in the question provide solutions to this equation. I don't understand how to proceed here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $ij=mn$ and $g:=\gcd(n,i)$ then: $$\frac{i}{g}\cdot j=m\cdot\frac{n}{g}$$

Here $\frac{i}{g}$ and $\frac{n}{g}$ are coprime integers.

Then the equality can only be true if $j$ is a multiple of $\frac{n}{g}$.

So $j=k\cdot\frac{n}{g}$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Finally $j\leq n$ implies that $k\leq g$.